# Use 2 label values for 1 template variable

Tags: prometheus, grafana

On my dashboard in Grafana, I wan't to have a template variable that select `id` from a metrics labels:

Here is the definition in my application using prometheus client in python:

```py
py_status = Enum("py_status", "...", labelsnames=["id", "name"], states=[...])
```

In grafana I setup my variable with the `query`:

```
label_value(py_status, id)
```

But for the confort of the user I wan't to display the to use the `name` when selecting it from the dashboard interface and use the `id` from the same query in the as value in the dashboard query. (knowing their is no duplicate `name` label)

Is it at least possible?

Comment: @markalex if I wan't to modify the display for example: name/short(id) = id, where short() is just the nth character of the entry, how can I do it or any reference about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with parsing results of your query by regex with named groups `text` and `value`.

For this:

1. change query type to *Query results*,
2. change query to `py_status`,
3. use following *Regex*:

```
/\bname="(?<text>[^"]+)|\bid="(?<value>[^"]+)/g
```

Here, alteration is used to parse results regardless of other labels and sequence. Additionally, `\b` prevents matching `id` in something like `parent_id`.

Otherwise, those selectors are usual regex, and you are free to adjust them as you need. For example, to extract only part after first `-` in label, you can use [`\bid="\[^—\]*?-(?<value>\[^"\]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/rx49qF/1).

---

Additional example in official documentation of Grafana can be found [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/variables/add-template-variables/#filter-and-modify-using-named-text-and-value-capture-groups).

Answer (score 0):

Thank's to @markalex.

Here is how I did it in my case, I set the `query` as:

```
py_status
```

and the `regex` with:

```
/name="(?<text>[^"]+)|id="(?<value>[^"]+)/g
```

That's giving me the `name` when the user select on the dashboard and use the `id` as value.

ref: [documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/variables/add-template-variables/#filter-and-modify-using-named-text-and-value-capture-groups)